# How to merge two pandas DataFrames, but without shared elements

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am scraping some NBA data with Python. I have the following script

```
def scrape_data():
    #URL
    url = "https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_advanced.html"
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    soup.findAll('tr', limit = 2)
    headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit = 2)[0].findAll('th')]
    headers = headers[1:]
    rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]for i in range(len(rows))]
    stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns=headers)
    stats.head(10)
    return stats
```

Which returns this

```
                       Player Pos Age   Tm   G  ...     OBPM  DBPM   BPM  VORP
0                Steven Adams   C  26  OKC  43  ...      1.6   3.3   4.9   2.0
1                 Bam Adebayo  PF  22  MIA  47  ...      1.2   3.8   5.0   2.8
2           LaMarcus Aldridge   C  34  SAS  43  ...      1.7   0.6   2.4   1.6
3    Nickeil Alexander-Walker  SG  21  NOP  38  ...     -3.4  -2.3  -5.6  -0.4
4               Grayson Allen  SG  24  MEM  30  ...     -0.7  -2.8  -3.5  -0.2
..                        ...  ..  ..  ...  ..  ... ..   ...   ...   ...   ...
537            Thaddeus Young  PF  31  CHI  49  ...     -2.2   0.9  -1.3   0.2
538                Trae Young  PG  21  ATL  44  ...      7.8  -2.3   5.5   2.9
539               Cody Zeller   C  27  CHO  45  ...      0.0  -0.6  -0.6   0.4
540                Ante Žižić   C  23  CLE  16  ...     -2.3  -1.4  -3.6  -0.1
541               Ivica Zubac   C  22  LAC  48  ...      0.4   2.3   2.7   1.0
```

I want to scrape a second url, where the table is formatted the exact same, and append the player's stats from this table to the other one, if that makes sense. The problem is, on the second url, there will be a few stats that are on both tables. I don't want to add these in again when I'm "merging" the two tables> How do I go about this?

Comment: When you say that a few stats are on both tables, do you mean the there are rows that are exactly the same in both tables (i.e. identical in all columns), or just that they have the same unique key (presumably the Player column)?

Comment: @croncroncron same unique key, and for example both tables shows a players PPG, I don’t want that to show twice

Comment: simply drop those columns in the second dataframe that are in the first dataframe. You will though need atleast 1 column in common to merge on (presumably player name...but be careful if there are players with the same name.You might need to merge on additional keys/columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doing a ton of work to put a `<table>` tag into a table. Let pandas do that for you (it uses BeautifulSoup under the hood). Then to merge, there's 2 ways you can do it:

1) Make one of the dataframes only have what is not contained in the other (However, keep columns that you will do the merge on).

2) Drop columns from the second dataframe that are in the dataframe (again, make sure to not drop the columns you will do the merge on.

```
import pandas as pd

def scrape_data(url):
    stats = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    return stats


df1 = scrape_data("https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_advanced.html")
df1 = df1[df1['Rk'] != 'Rk']

df2 = scrape_data("https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_per_poss.html")
df2 = df2[df2['Rk'] != 'Rk']

uniqueCols = [ col for col in df2.columns if col not in df1.columns ]

# Below will do the same as above line
#uniqueCols = list(df2.columns.difference(df1.columns))

df2 = df2[uniqueCols + ['Player', 'Tm']]

df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Player', 'Tm'])
```

OR

```
import pandas as pd

def scrape_data(url):
    stats = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    return stats


df1 = scrape_data("https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_advanced.html")
df1 = df1[df1['Rk'] != 'Rk']

df2 = scrape_data("https://basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_per_poss.html")
df2 = df2[df2['Rk'] != 'Rk']

dropCols = [ col for col in df1.columns if col in df2.columns and col not in ['Player','Tm']]
df2 = df2.drop(dropCols, axis=1)

df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Player', 'Tm'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use drop_duplicates(). Here's a simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["foo", "bar"],["foo2", "bar2"],["foo3", "bar3"]], columns=["first_column", "second_column"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["foo3", "bar4"],["foo4", "bar5"],["foo5", "bar6"]], columns=["first_column", "second_column"])

print(pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset="first_column"))
```

Output:

```
  first_column second_column
0          foo           bar
1         foo2          bar2
2         foo3          bar3
4         foo4          bar5
5         foo5          bar6
```

As you can see, the "foo3" row from the second dataframe gets filtered out because it is already contained in the first dataframe.

In your case you would use something like:

```
pd.concat([stats, stats2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset="Player"))
```